# Javascript links and google seo

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I have an xml file which would contain links to several internal html pages. I am using HTML DOM to get these links and display the links in a table. These links are simple html links and no parameters. These html pages reside in the server.

My question is, when I used fetch as google in webmaster tools. google is fetching the javascript but not the table that is populated. Will google crawl and index these links? I want to make sure that these pages linked here will be indexed... Please guide me through this issue. Also let me know if there would be a better way to display content from xml so that google crawls these links.

```
<script>
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/jobs/jobs.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
document.write('<table id="example">');
document.write('<thead><tr><th>Job ID</th><th>Job Title</th><th class=\"mobexcl\">Location</th><th class=\"mobexcl\">Country</th><th class=\"mobexcl\">Date Posted</th><th>Status</th><th class=\"mobexcl\">View</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                  { 
                  if(i%2==0){
                  document.write('<tr class="alt">');
                   }
                  else{
                  document.write('<tr class="alt1">');
                   }
                  document.write("<td>");
                  document.write('<a href="' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("VIEW")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '">'+x[i].getElementsByTagName("JOBID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</a>');
                  document.write("</td><td>");
                  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  document.write("</td><td class=\"mobexcl\">");
                  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("LOCATION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  document.write("</td><td class=\"mobexcl\">");
                  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  document.write("</td><td class=\"mobexcl\">");
                  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  document.write("</td><td>");
                  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("STATUS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                  document.write("</td><td class=\"mobexcl\">");
                  document.write('<a href="' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("VIEW")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '">View/Apply</a>');
                  document.write("</td></tr>");
                  }
document.write("</tbody></table>");
</script>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Crawlers won't execute scripts on your page.

Google has devised a method to crawl ajax populated sites. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Third item in the list seems to be applicable to your case.

Basically, your server needs to create a HTML snapshot of the ajax rendered page for google bot to crawl.

Google also provides tool to test this setup.

HTH.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Is there a simple way to achieve this. Is there a step by step guide anywhere? I am having trouble understanding the easiest way to set up html snapshots.

Comment: The easiest way would be to save your ajax populated page from the browser to a file and then serve it as a static html on your server for the url `www.yoursite.com?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: Hello, Sorry for asking late. I have a question. IF my current ajax page is lets say, www.mysite.com/pag1.html then do I create a static page with file name page1?_escaped_fragment_= . will there not be an extension for the filename like .html? I little confused here, please guide me.